# How to add variable to a href

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I want to do something like this

```
var myname = req.session.name;              <------- dynamic
<a href="/upload?name=" + myname class="btn btn-info btn-md">
```

But this does not work. So how do I properly pass in a dynamic variable to href? `<a href="/upload?name=" + req.session.name class="btn btn-info btn-md">` does not work either

Comment: You really need to learn the difference between html and javascript - what their respective capabilities and limitations are.  Take a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there's no way to add a js variable strictly inside DOM. I would suggest you to apply an `id` attribute to that `a` element, refer to it and apply given variable as a new `href` attribute.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('a'),
    myname = 'req.session.name';   //used it as a string, just for test cases
    elem.href += myname;
    
    console.log(elem.href);
```

```html
<a id='a' href="/upload?name=" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Link</a>
```

Comment: this is like a hack around it

Comment: how is this answer better than @senthuranambalavanar 's?

Comment: @jebmarcus It's not a hack around. It seems like the most proper way out. But if you prefer Senthuran solution, feel free to use it.

Comment: Thanks @kinduser I am just curious to know what makes it the most proper way :) I am trying to learn

Comment: @jebmarcus See my comment on Senthuran's answer. There are actually some rules about when you should use certain HTML elements, even if frameworks like Bootstrap make them more difficult to see.

Comment: @jebmarcus Agreed with Mike. Anyways, making a separate function for every single element doesn't seem effective for me. A different story about window object. I've worked with replacing links using `window.location` not once, nor twice and sometimes I was facing some unexpected issues with it. I do not recommend it.